# Oracle Date Range Inconsistancy

Tags: performance, oracle, range, long-integer

I am running a fairly large query on a specific range of dates. The query takes about 30 seconds EXCEPT when I do a range of 10/01/2011-10/31/2011. For some reason that range never finishes. For example 01/01/2011-01/31/2011, and pretty much every other range, finishes in the expected time.

Also, I noticed that doing smaller ranges, like a week, takes longer than larger ranges.

Comment: Are you using bind variables or are you using hard-coded literals?  What version of Oracle are you using?  Is there a histogram on the date column?  Are the statistics (including that histogram) accurate?  Are you getting different query plans?  If so, what do the "good" plans look like and what do the "bad" plans look like?

Comment: We are using 10g and I am using bind variables. I am pretty sure that there is not a histogram on the date column. I am actually a Java developer and I am not really familiar with histograms. There is an index on that column and it is being used. The query plans are quite different when I change the date. I never though to check that as I thought the plan would be the same if the query is the same. The bad plan uses a lot of nested loops while the good one uses none. Also, the bad plan is using an operation I have not seen before "View Pushed Predicate".

Comment: Looking at the column stats I noticed the last analysis was on 9/26/2011. By forcing an updated analysis the problem is fixed. The question I have now is why were the stats stale and what can I tell our DBA to do to make sure that they stay up to date?

Answer (score 2):

When Oracle gathers statistics on a table, it will record the low value and the high value in a date column and use that to estimate the cardinality of a predicate.  If you create a histogram on the column, it will gather more detailed information about the distribution of data within the column.  Otherwise, Oracle's cost based optimizer (CBO) will assume a uniform distribution.

For example, if you have a table with 1 million rows and a `DATE` column with a low value of January 1, 2001 and a high value of January 1, 2011, it will assume that the approximately 10% of the data is in the range January 1, 2001 - January 1, 2002 and that roughly 0.027% of the data would come from some time on March 3, 2008 (1/(10 years * 365 days per year + leap days).

So long as your queries use dates from within the known range, the optimizer's cardinality estimates are generally pretty good so its decisions about what plan to use are pretty good.  If you go a bit beyond the upper or lower bound, the estimates are still pretty good because the optimizer assumes that there probably is data that is larger or smaller than it saw when it sampled the data to gather the statistics.  But when you get too far from the range that the optimizer statistics expect to see, the optimizer's cardinality estimates get too far out of line and it eventually chooses a bad plan.  In your case, prior to refreshing the statistics, the maximum value the optimizer was expecting was probably September 25 or 26, 2011.  When your query looked for data for the month of October, 2011, the optimizer most likely expected that the query would return very few rows and chose a plan that was optimized for that scenario rather than for the larger number of rows that were actually returned.  That caused the plan to be much worse given the actual volume of data that was returned.

In Oracle 10.2, when Oracle does a hard parse and generates a plan for a query that is loaded into the shared pool, it peeks at the bind variable values and uses those values to estimate the number of rows a query will return and thus the most efficient query plan.  Once a query plan has been created and until the plan is aged out of the shared pool, subsequent executions of the same query will use the same query plan regardless of the values of the bind variables.  Of course, the next time the query has to be hard parsed because the plan was aged out, Oracle will peek and will likely see new bind variable values.

[Bind variable peeking](http://kerryosborne.oracle-guy.com/2009/03/bind-variable-peeking-drives-me-nuts/) is not a particularly well-loved feature (Adaptive Cursor Sharing in 11g is *much* better) because it makes it very difficult for a DBA or a developer to predict what plan is going to be used at any particular instant because you're never sure if the bind variable values that the optimizer saw during the hard parse are representative of the bind variable values you generally see.  For example, if you are searching over a 1 day range, an index scan would almost certainly be more efficient.  If you're searching over a 5 year range, a table scan would almost certainly be more efficient.  But you end up using whatever plan was chosen during the hard parse.

Most likely, you can resolve the problem simply by ensuring that statistics are gathered more frequently on tables that are frequently queried based on ranges of monotonically increasing values (date columns being by far the most common such column).  In your case, it had been roughly 6 weeks since statistics had been gathered before the problem arose so it would probably be safe to ensure that statistics are gathered on this table every month or every couple weeks depending on how costly it is to gather statistics.

You could also use the [`DBMS_STATS.SET_COLUMN_STATS`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#i997460) procedure to explicitly set the statistics for this column on a more regular basis.  That requires more coding and work but saves you the time of gathering statistics.  That can be hugely beneficial in a data warehouse environment but it's probably overkill in a more normal OLTP environment.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation Justin. You're making me want to brush up on my DB tuning skills.